# Getting TensorFlow to use double precision for custom classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, decorator, precision

Consider the following TensorFlow code, which does not use Keras. I would like TensorFlow to perform the calculations in double precision. For the function `tfmult` I was able to figure out how to pass arguments to the `tf.function` decorator. Now if I put my variables in a class `Data` and define my multiplication function `datamult`, how do I apply `tf.function` to `datamult` so that computations are carried out in double precision?

```
import tensorflow as tf

# this doesn't help - because I'm not using keras
# tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')

aa = 1.00006
bb = 1.00007

def simplemult(aa,bb):
    return aa*bb

# I can use arguments to the decorator to get tf to treat the arguments as float64
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=None,dtype=tf.float64),tf.TensorSpec(shape=None,dtype=tf.float64)])
def tfmult(aa,bb):
    return aa*bb

# Now let us put the numbers inside a class
class Data():
    def __init__(self,xx):
        self.xx = xx
       
p1 = Data(aa)
p2 = Data(bb)

# How do I apply a tf.function decorator to this function so that operations are done in double precision
# @tf.function - defaults to single precision
@tf.function
def datamult(p1,p2):
    return (p1.xx)*(p2.xx)

print(f'{tfmult(aa,bb)=}')
print(f'{simplemult(aa,bb)=}')
print(f'{datamult(p1,p2)=}')
```